# How to get two type of indices at the same time by numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a ndarray `z`, and would like to get following indices

```
z_idxes1 = np.argwhere(z == i)
z_idxes2 = np.argwhere(z != i)
```

Can we do this in one call to some numpy function rather than two calls of argwhere?

Comment: How do you intend to use these index arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in one call, but you can use logical not operator to get the negation of your mask array.

```
mask = (z == i)
z_idxes1 = np.argwhere(mask)

z_idxes2 = np.argwhere(~mask)
```

Comment: argwhere doesn't produce a Boolean mask.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, you're right. Why on earth I thought it returns a boolean mask :)?!!.